# Firebase Google Sign in check if User phone Number is empty

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am using google sign in for my android application and I want to check if my current user's phone number is empty and then take an action. I tried putting an if statement and it is throwing me null pointer exception. Can someone please help me to fix this issue ?

```
 String userNumber = user.getPhoneNumber();
  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Verifying your phone number information...");
      if(userNumber.isEmpty()) {
          Intent phoneAuth = new Intent(GoogleSignIn.this, 
                                          PhoneAuthentication.class);
          startActivity(phoneAuth);
          finish();
      }
```

This is the error :

```
08-03 19:09:24.680 29877-29877/com.manali.phonegooglecontacts D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
08-03 19:09:24.683 29877-29877/com.manali.phonegooglecontacts D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
08-03 19:09:24.684 29877-29877/com.manali.phonegooglecontacts E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.manali.phonegooglecontacts, PID: 29877
                                                                                java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.manali.phonegooglecontacts.GoogleSignIn$1.onComplete(GoogleSignIn.java:132)
                                                                                    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Comment: May be you should do this 'null != userNumber' before 'userNumber.isEmpty()' . Or use one of the TextUtil utilities

Comment: instead of using `userNumber.isEmpty()`, use `userNumber === null` (in case of empty) and `userNumber != null` (in case of not empty)

Comment: it make hard when phone number is null then we have to do this manually with authentication, actually after sign in it should provide the user phone number , it so sad

Answer (score 0):

actully you wants to get phone number as a unique id, so its sometimes null, and email you can not use as unique id  for firebase as it contains some letter that can not be stored in firebase, so if you wants to get phone only due to store as unique id then do not, just get

user.getid();